# Header content disposition allow &amp character

Tags: php, header, save, filenames

and sorry for my bad english..

I come again with some problems to you!

I use that bellow lines of code:

```
$link = $_GET['url'];
$name = $_GET['name'];
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: private");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"(wanted-web.ro) $name.mp3\"");
header("Content-type: audio/mpeg;\r\n");
readfile(str_replace(' ', '_', $link));
```

That code is used for a download direct links .mp3 from external server!

My problem is:
When i download some file containing **&** character, dont show the rest of informations after that character!!

For example:
**Rihanna & Akon**

.. Allways save me the file with name **Rihanna** ..
Corect was **Rihanna & Akon** , but the amp character stop showing and **Akon**

I've tried many different methods, but allways fail..

For better explanation, that script is a php download file..
When i click to download **Rihanna & Akon** , show me the prompt download box!
In download box show me only **Rihanna** , but never and **Akon** if contain **&** character after **Rihanna**

Hope to understand something !

Thank you in advance !!
Cheers!

Comment: you need to URL encode special characters, to be included there. you can simply pass the filename from PHP's `urlencode()` function.

Comment: can u show me a litle example? Sorry, but im newbie in php! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to `urlencode` the file name, like this:

```
$name = urlencode($_GET['name']);
```

Comment: Now apear with "+" character .. example: Rihanna+   ..Thank you for your response!

Comment: Does using `rawurlencode` instead of `urlencode` solve your problem?

Comment: With rawurlencode show me Rihanna%20  .. I dont know what to do more! Im tired trying to fix that problem!

Answer (score 0):

encoding for your code sample above would be

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"(wanted-web.ro) "
  .urlencode($name). ".mp3\"");
```

Comment: Same again!! Now apear with "+" character .. example: Rihanna+ ..Thank you for your response!

Comment: if you only need it for showing the name to the visitor, you can replace `urlencode()` with `htmlentities()` -- that will convert the characters for display.

Comment: No result with htmlentities ! Maybe it's something wrong in my php script! .. I dont know what to do more.. Thank you so much for you trying to help me!